# ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is connecting. in execute reader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, c#-4.0

Here i use my webmethod.But when i going to connect it shows this error.But my code is good i think.

> ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is connecting.

MyCode

```
public static List<CommonPages> GetCommonPagesDescription(int Type)
{
    List<CommonPages> CommonPageDescription = new List<CommonPages>();
    try
    {
        SqlCommand comGetAllFiles = new SqlCommand("GetCommonPageDescriptions", conDB);
        comGetAllFiles.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if (conDB.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conDB.Open(); // <-- Debugger Skip this & goto next line
        comGetAllFiles.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.Int);
        comGetAllFiles.Parameters["@Type"].Value = Type;

        SqlDataReader rdr = comGetAllFiles.ExecuteReader();//<-- error generating here
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(rdr);
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            CommonPageDescription.Add(new CommonPages
            {
                Id = (int)r["Id"],
                Description = r["Description"].ToString(),
                Type = (int)r["Type"],
                UpdatedDate = (DateTime)r["UpdatedDate"],
                UpdatedBy = (Guid)r["UpdatedBy"]

            });
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        conDB.Close();
    }
    return CommonPageDescription;
}
```

conDB Initialized here

```
 static SqlConnection conDB = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: show  the code where conDB is initialized...

Comment: This is easy to avoid if you just create a new connection object, open it, do your work, then dispose of the connection.  An empty catch is rarely a good thing, by the way.

Comment: What's `connDB.State`?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are being passed a connection that is in the "connecting" state, maybe it was opened asynchronously or something. Your State == Closed check doesn't execute the Open method.

Comment: The error message tells you the problem.  `conDB.State == ConnectionState.Connecting`.

Comment: @apomene  static SqlConnection conDB = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString);

Comment: @Mark Yes open method not executing here..How do i solve this ?

Comment: @RickS how to solve it ?

Comment: You could try if(conn.State != ConnectionSTate.Open) conn.Open(). I don't know if that works in certain states though.

Comment: There are plenty of comments to help you solve this problem.

Comment: @TechGuy your edit does not provide the information that I asked for.

Comment: @Mark. Checked,no luck

Comment: @TechGuy how did you check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of opening the connection when it is closed, try to open the connection when it is not opened.

```
public static List<CommonPages> GetCommonPagesDescription(int Type)
{
    List<CommonPages> CommonPageDescription = new List<CommonPages>();
    try
    {
        SqlCommand comGetAllFiles = new SqlCommand("GetCommonPageDescriptions", conDB);
        comGetAllFiles.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if (conDB.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            conDB.Open(); // <-- Debugger Skip this & goto next line
        comGetAllFiles.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.Int);
        comGetAllFiles.Parameters["@Type"].Value = Type;

        SqlDataReader rdr = comGetAllFiles.ExecuteReader();//<-- error generating here
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(rdr);
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            CommonPageDescription.Add(new CommonPages
            {
                Id = (int)r["Id"],
                Description = r["Description"].ToString(),
                Type = (int)r["Type"],
                UpdatedDate = (DateTime)r["UpdatedDate"],
                UpdatedBy = (Guid)r["UpdatedBy"]

            });
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        conDB.Close();
    }
    return CommonPageDescription;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`conDB` must be a shared connection?  Probably not a good idea, leverage connection pooling.

To fix it, consider opening and closing a `connection` per request.  Don't care if the voodoo sayers that this inefficient, in truth you want to open/close connections as little as possible but sometimes you need to go to the DB for a single reason.  There are ways you could share a connection better, using a `context` pattern for example.  But to solve your immediate problem structure your DB calls this way.

```
try
{
  using( System.Data.Common.DbConnection conn = CreateConnection() )
  {
     //create your command...
     //create your reader/or execute your command...
  }
}
```

Comment: How to solve it.. pls check my updated question